# How to find the moment of inertia of an object when we know the moment of inertia of its symetric part?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I am getting a little bit confused with calculating moment of inertia of symetric objects.

For example if the task was to find $I$ of a thin equilateral triangular plate of mass $m$ and side $a$ about an axis through its center (perpendicular to the plane). If I divide the triangle into $6$ same parts and find the moment of inertia of one part (about the axis through the center of the whole triangle) why can't I multiply the result by $6$ to get the total moment of inertia?

[image: Triangle]

Here if I count the moment of inertia for the whole triangle:
$$I = \rho \int_{-\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{6}}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{3}} \int_{-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{a}{3}}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{a}{3}} (x^2+y^2)\, dy \, dx = \frac{1}{12}ma^2$$

And now if I count the moment of inertia for just one sixth of the triangle (about an axis around its corner which would be the center of the whole triangle) I also get $I = \frac{1}{12}ma^2$ $$I = \rho \int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{6}} \int_{0}^{\frac{3x}{\sqrt{3}}} (x^2+y^2)\, dy \, dx = \frac{1}{12}ma^2$$

My question is shouldn't the moment of inertia of the whole triangle be six times bigger than the moment of inertia of one sixth?

Another examples:
If I have disc and the task is to find moment of inertia of the full disc about an axis through its center (perpendicular to the plane), why can't (or can) I find the moment of inertia of just $\frac{1}{4}$ of the disc (about the axis though the center of a full dics) and multiply the result by $4$ to get the moment of inertia of a full disc?

[image: Disc]

Last example - moment of inertia of an triangle about an axis through its height. Can I calculate $I$ of half the triangle with respect to the given axis and after that multiply the result by $2$ to get the moment of inertia of the whole triangle?

Comment: I guess you used in both integrals $\rho=m/S$ where $S$ is the surface of integration. In this way the whole triangle and the piece have the same mass, and you get the same result just for the symmetry. You should use the same value for $\rho$ in both cases.

Comment: @GCLL I am not sure if I understand correctly but are you suggesting that the moment of inertia of the whole triangle is going to be six times larger because its mass is six times larger?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can easily check if this is the case: in the two integrals the value used for $\rho$ should be the same, in order to make a fair comparison.

Comment: Well, that's great. Thank you. So it works for all cases. Generally sail, if I have an object and want to count its moment of inertia with respect to any given axis I can "split" the object into as many parts as I want and count the moment of inertia of the individual parts with respect to the original given axes and to get the moment of inertia of the whole object I would just sum all moments of inertia of the individial parts, correct?

Comment: Yes, the momentum of inertia is additive. And this is independent from the existence of a symmetry. Additionally if you have a geometrical transformation which do not change the distance of each point from the axis, the momentum of inertia does not change. Transformation of this kind are rotations around the axis, and reflections with respect to  a plane passing through the axis. You are using both of them in your example of the triangle. More explicitly: if the reference axis is $z$, all the transformations which do not change $x^2+y^2$ are good ones.